# Python: Changing variables in another class from another

Tags: python

I have two files like the following

file1.py

```
class A:
 def method1:
  a = 5
```

file2.py

```
class B
 def method2:
  from file1 import A
   a = 10
```

Forget the logic, its just an example. I wish to manipulate the value of a in my code. When I do this it gives me an error saying
"global name a is not defined". How can I solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is `a` supposed to be a module-level variable in `file1`?

Comment: I suspect you may be missing the idea of what a class is. It's hard to tell from what little (syntactically broken) code you've shown.

Comment: No, we can't just forget the logic. This is a very unclear question, and changing global variables within other classes seems like a good way to break the positive advantages of OOP. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My file2.py is using file1.py to find a solution. But it needs to find the solution 4 times and append the solution it found each time. So I want to reset the value of a in file1.py to its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined a it is a local variable to that method.  What you want is self.a...

file1.py

```
class A:
    def method1:
        self.a = 5
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import A
class B:
    def method2:
        objecta = A()
        objecta.a = 10
```

But reading your comments, what you actually want is something different.

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

    def logic(self):
        do some stuff...

Class B:
    def solve(self):
        first = A()
        first.logic()
        second = A()
        second.logic()
        etc...
```

The point of doing it with classes is that you can make multiple instances of the class.  The init function creates an object of that class based on your baseline- so each time you make an A object, it will start out with your original settings.